# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" in a dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm building a server with NodeJS, Typescript, Typeorm and ts-node.

The first line in one of my files I'm importing:

`import { build } from 'compassql/build/src/schema';`

And, when I run the code I got the error:

```
/Users/paulomenezes/repositories/juno/server/node_modules/compassql/build/src/schema.js:1
import dlBin_ from 'datalib/src/bins/bins';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/paulomenezes/repositories/juno/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:384:14)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulomenezes/repositories/juno/server/src/service/dashboard.service.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The lib that I'm importing is [CompassQL](https://github.com/vega/compassql).

The error isn't in my project, but it's in the library, when I open the `/node_module/compassql/build/src/schema.js`, the javascript file has a import syntax:

`import dlBin_ from 'datalib/src/bins/bins';`

And I think that is the error, my dependency is using a syntax that is not supported in my project, but how I can fix this?

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./node_modules/compassql/typings/*.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/vega-lite/typings/*.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts",
    "typings/*.d.ts",
    "typings/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules/compassql/typings/json.d.ts", "./node_modules/vega-lite/typings/json.d.ts", "./node_modules/vega-lite/typings/vega.d.ts"]
}
```

And here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/d3": "^6.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.4",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.2.2",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "yalc": "^1.0.0-pre.49"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@junoapp/common": "file:.yalc/@junoapp/common",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "clickhouse": "^2.1.5",
    "compassql": "^0.21.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "datalib": "^1.9.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firstline": "^2.0.2",
    "got": "^11.7.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "typeorm": "0.2.25",
    "vega-typings": "^0.19.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --max-old-space-size=8000 --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts",
    "yalc:update": "yalc update"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  }
}
```

My project complies normally without this import:

`import { build } from 'compassql/build/src/schema';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve my problem switching the `ts-node` for `Webpack` for some reason, this erros was not happing with Webpack config. This is my config files:

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const NodemonPlugin = require('nodemon-webpack-plugin');
const FilterWarningsPlugin = require('webpack-filter-warnings-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  target: 'node',
  externals: {
    express: 'require("express")',
    'app-root-path': 'require("app-root-path")',
    keyv: 'require("keyv")',
    'sync-rpc': 'require("sync-rpc")',
    typeorm: 'require("typeorm")',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', 'json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    ],
  },
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^pg-native$/ }),
    new NodemonPlugin(),
    new FilterWarningsPlugin({
      exclude: [/mongodb/, /mssql/, /mysql/, /mysql2/, /oracledb/, /redis/, /sqlite3/, /sql.js/, /react-native-sqlite-storage/, /typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver/, /@sap\/hdbext/, /pg-query-stream/],
    }),
  ],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "strict": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

and my `package.json`

```
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/d3": "^6.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.4",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.2.2",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.8",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.13",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-filter-warnings-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "yalc": "^1.0.0-pre.49"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@junoapp/common": "file:.yalc/@junoapp/common",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "clickhouse": "^2.1.5",
    "compassql": "^0.21.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "datalib": "^1.9.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firstline": "^2.0.2",
    "got": "^11.7.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "typeorm": "0.2.25",
    "vega-typings": "^0.19.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "yalc:update": "yalc update"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `import` in your project code, remember to say `type: "module"` in your `package.json` so that Node knows that you're writing modern ES module code, and not legacy CommonJS code. It looks like you're missing that field at the moment - in addition to fixing that, it's probably worth giving https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling a read-through as well, just to get up to speed on the particulars of writing modern `esm` code with Node 14/15.

Also, note that module packages can require `cjs` modules, but not vice versa, so if you have a legacy project that relies on `require` rather than `import`, it won't be able to require libraries if they've been released specifically for `esm` use (although `npm` allows packages to specify two different exports, one for use with `require` and one for use with `import` so this is rarely an actual problem, but good to be aware of).

Comment: When I add the `type: "module"` I got this error:

```TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION] [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/paulomenezes/repositories/juno/server/src/index.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:278:15)
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:71:15)
    [...]
    at Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:165:17)
    at Object.loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:68:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...```

Comment: Of course? Node itself has no idea what typescript is. Unlike deno or bun it only knows javascript. if you want to work with typescript, follow a (current) "how to use typescript with node" tutorial.